# InfoPath - Checkbox remains checked even if unchecked

Tags: infopath, survey

I have created a survey with 10 questions. 
I have set option buttons and check boxes too. 
Option button works fine but there is an issue with the check box.

E.g. I have a question with 4 answers. A, B, C, D. 
I start thinking about the answer and choose A and B, but in the meantime 
I realize that the correct answer is the C and the D. 
I uncheck A and B and check C and D. 
The issue is that when I submit the form it shows me that all 4 options has been checked hence the answer is wrong.

Do you might have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go with "Set a Field's Value" rule (picture 1) and set the answers field to " " (empty) when the button is NOT checked. (picture 2)

So when it is checked, it will copy the given letter to the given field (to see what answer was chosen), but when it is not checked it remains empty.

See screenshots.

[image]

[image]